# Saving image as PNG-24 in IrfanView

Tags: png, irfanview

Is it possible to save an image as PNG-24 in IrfanView?

I am asking this because the edges around circular lines get disturbed when saving the image as transparent. I heard that this might be [due to PNG-8 format](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/7192/4407).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the image, choose Image, Increase Color Depth and choose the 16million color option.

When you save as PNG it will be PNG-24 (ie, 24-bit color) format.

That may or may not solve the problem of raggedy edges.

Comment: Thank you for the instructions. This worked indeed. But "Increase Color Depth" was disabled. As a workaround, I selected first "Decrease Color Depth". After that "Increase Color Depth" became enabled.

Comment: If "Increase Color Depth" was disabled, it's almost certainly because it was already a 24-bit image.